# DropPath in TIMM seems like a Dropout?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

The code below (taken from [here](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/blob/a6e8598aaf90261402f3e9e9a3f12eac81356e9d/timm/models/layers/drop.py#L140)) seems to implement only a simple `Dropout`, neither the `DropPath` nor `DropConnect`. Is that true?

```py
def drop_path(x, drop_prob: float = 0., training: bool = False):
    """Drop paths (Stochastic Depth) per sample (when applied in main path of residual blocks).
    This is the same as the DropConnect impl I created for EfficientNet, etc networks, however,
    the original name is misleading as 'Drop Connect' is a different form of dropout in a separate paper...
    See discussion: https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/issues/494#issuecomment-532968956 ... I've opted for
    changing the layer and argument names to 'drop path' rather than mix DropConnect as a layer name and use
    'survival rate' as the argument.
    """
    if drop_prob == 0. or not training:
        return x
    keep_prob = 1 - drop_prob
    shape = (x.shape[0],) + (1,) * (x.ndim - 1)  # work with diff dim tensors, not just 2D ConvNets
    random_tensor = keep_prob + torch.rand(shape, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
    random_tensor.floor_()  # binarize
    output = x.div(keep_prob) * random_tensor
    return output
```

Answer (score 13):

No, it is different from [`Dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html):

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.functional import dropout

torch.manual_seed(2021)

def drop_path(x, drop_prob: float = 0., training: bool = False):
    if drop_prob == 0. or not training:
        return x
    keep_prob = 1 - drop_prob
    shape = (x.shape[0],) + (1,) * (x.ndim - 1)
    random_tensor = keep_prob + torch.rand(shape, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
    random_tensor.floor_()  # binarize
    output = x.div(keep_prob) * random_tensor
    return output

x = torch.rand(3, 2, 2, 2)

# DropPath
d1_out = drop_path(x, drop_prob=0.33, training=True)

# Dropout
d2_out = dropout(x, p=0.33, training=True)
```

Let's compare the outputs (I removed the line break between channel dimension for readability):

```py
# DropPath
print(d1_out)
#  tensor([[[[0.1947, 0.7662],
#            [1.1083, 1.0685]],
#           [[0.8515, 0.2467],
#            [0.0661, 1.4370]]],
#
#          [[[0.0000, 0.0000],
#            [0.0000, 0.0000]],
#           [[0.0000, 0.0000],
#            [0.0000, 0.0000]]],
#
#          [[[0.7658, 0.4417],
#            [1.1692, 1.1052]],
#           [[1.2014, 0.4532],
#            [1.4840, 0.7499]]]])

# Dropout
print(d2_out)
#  tensor([[[[0.1947, 0.7662],
#            [1.1083, 1.0685]],
#           [[0.8515, 0.2467],
#            [0.0661, 1.4370]]],
#
#          [[[0.0000, 0.1480],
#            [1.2083, 0.0000]],
#           [[1.2272, 0.1853],
#            [0.0000, 0.5385]]],
#
#          [[[0.7658, 0.0000],
#            [1.1692, 1.1052]],
#           [[1.2014, 0.4532],
#            [0.0000, 0.7499]]]])
```

As you can see, they are different. `DropPath` is dropping an entire sample from the batch, which effectively results in *stochastic depth* when used as in Eq. 2 of their [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.09382.pdf). On the other hand, `Dropout` is dropping random values, as expected (from the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html)):

> During training, **randomly zeroes some of the elements of the input tensor** with probability `p` using samples from a Bernoulli distribution. Each channel will be zeroed out independently on every forward call.

Also note that both scale the output values based on the probability, i.e., the non-zeroed out elements are identical for the same `p`.

Comment: Seems like drop a sample randomly? What's the meaning of that?

Comment: @inkzk A batch is a set of samples. `DropPath` is dropping samples (the actual number of samples will depend on the probability and RNG, of course) from the batch, which results in *stochastic depth*, when applied to Eq. 2 of the paper. Check the zeroes in `d1_out`. Please, consider upvoting if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `droppath` is used together with residual connections.
For example:

```
x = x + droppath(block(x))
```

If `block(x)` is dropped, it equals to say `block()` is skipped and the input x is output directly.